# How to rationalise the 'pro-' prefix in 'promiscuous' ?

Tags: etymology

I ask not about [the definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promiscuous?q=promiscuous+) itself,  but about the impact or role of the prefix in English:

> [promiscuous (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=promiscuous&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       c.1600, people or things, "mingled confusedly, grouped together without order, consisting of a disorderly mix; indiscriminate," from Latin *promiscuus* "mixed, indiscriminate, in common, without distinction," **from *pro-* "forward" (see [pro-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pro-&allowed_in_frame=0))** + *miscere* "to mix" (see [mix](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mix&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). Meaning "indiscriminate in sexual relations" recorded by 1857, from [promiscuity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=promiscuity&allowed_in_frame=0). The Latin adjective was used with *conubia* (such as between patricians and plebeians). Related: *Promiscuously*.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking!

Comment: @WS2 I'm asking how 'pro-' matters in 'promiscuous'? In what sense is 'promiscuous'**"forward"**? Better? Please advise if I should explain more?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based upon [the Etymological Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: The question is based upon a false premise. Assuming that *pro-* prefix only and necessarily means *forward* in all cases would lead to an eternal listing of this question for every word that begins with *pro*. Take a look at the pro- link in the OP and also the idea of the antonym or even removal of the pro- prefix.  If miscere means to mix, and going forward with mixing is evident in one who is given such attribute, this doesn't seem to be that difficult of a reach.

Comment: @SrJoven Thank you. I recognise the Etymological Fallacy, but forgot to include it in the OP. Your last sentence clarified the linchpin that eluded me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general meaning of **pro-** is forward but the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pro-&searchmode=none) suggests several derived connotations:

> word-forming element meaning "forward, forth, toward the front" (as in
>   proclaim, proceed);
>
> "beforehand, in advance" (prohibit, provide);
>
> "taking care of" (procure);
>
> "in place of, on behalf of" (proconsul, pronoun);
>
> from Latin pro "on behalf of, in place of, before, for, in exchange
>   for, just as," which also was used as a prefix.
>
> Also in some cases from cognate Greek pro "before, in front of,
>   sooner," which also was used in Greek as a prefix (as in problem).
>   Both the Latin and Greek words are from PIE *pro- (cognates: Sanskrit
>   pra- "before, forward, forth;" Gothic faura "before," Old English fore
>   "before, for, on account of," fram "forward, from;" Old Irish roar
>   "enough"), extended form of root *per- (1) "forward, through" (see
>   per).
>
> The common modern sense "in favor of, favoring" (pro-independence,
>   pro-fluoridation, pro-Soviet, etc.) was not in classical Latin and is
>   attested in English from early 19c.

Examining [early usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promiscuous&year_start=1600&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromiscuous%3B%2Cc0), seems to suggest the possibility of *mixing* ***before*** investigation, inspection, or approval of an authority: *indiscriminate*. This fits seamlessly with the currently dominant connotation of *[indiscriminate sexual activity](https://books.google.com/books?id=6t3DpP9mTJsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22promiscuous%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YZXFVJLjHIHasATR3YLQAQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22promiscuous%22&f=false)*, which was **originally** defined as sexual activity outside the legal or religious sanction of marriage.

Comment: +1. Thank you! Your last para (after the quote) clarified the linchpin that eluded me!